# Symfony delete a bundle manually

Tags: php, bundle, symfony

I tried to delete a bundle manually, but an error appeared...
I guess I forgot an essential edition, but I don't know what.
I deleted the file of that bundle, I delete its line in the `AppKernel`, and I deleted it's lines in the `app/routing.yml`.

Here is the error :

> FileLoaderLoadException in FileLoader.php line 118:
>   Bundle "DbToYmlBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the registerBundles() method of your AppKernel.php file? in @DbToYmlBundle/Resources/config/services.yml (which is being imported from "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dublin/app/config/config.yml"). Make sure the "DbToYmlBundle" bundle is correctly registered and loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make sure the bundle path "@DbToYmlBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" is not empty.

Could someone help to find what is wrong ?

Comment: i'd use a tool with a multiple files search (such as Notepad++ or Eclipse) and look for "DbToYmlBundle" in the whole project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message states that the `@DbToYmlBundle/Resources/config/services.yml` is imported from `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dublin/app/config/config.yml`

Please check your `config.yml`'s or provide some more information/codes, maybe the output for your `prod.log` `/opt/lampp/htdocs/dublin/app/logs/prod.log`

Comment: it was in the app/config.yml, thank you so much ! I didn't see that line, whereas I searched during 2 hours... Thank you !!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to clear the cache with the console. 
For the Dev environment:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

And for production environment :

```
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Comment: Do you mean `php bin/…`? The `P` may cause problems.

Comment: Yes sorry, I wrote "Php" but I would write "Php". Thanks for your comment.

Comment: I made a second time the same mistake : understand "php" as good write.

Comment: Do you use a keyboard on a mobile device? It may change `php` to `Php`. I updated your answer.